# API Path Encoding

Tags: javascript, dropbox

So I've been pounding my head against the wall for days on this one .. Using Javascript I'm trying to encode the path for API calls to Dropbox.  Dropbox takes the following url

```
https://api.dropbox.com/1/shares/dropbox/<path>
```

So let's say I have a file 'Getting Started.pdf' in my root folder .. access to the shares or any other api call should be something like

```
https://api.dropbox.com/1/shares/dropbox/Getting%20Started.pdf
```

However, I'm returned this error

```
{"statusCode":404,"data":"{\"error\": \"Path '/Getting%20Started.pdf' not found\"}"}
```

Removing the url encoding for spaces seems to work, but causes issues for file names with other special character like &

```
https://api.dropbox.com/1/shares/dropbox/some %26 some.txt
```

Anyone know exactly how the url is expected to be encoded?

[edit] Here is my encoding function

```
p = encodeURIComponent(utf8)
            .replace(/%2F/g, '/')
            .replace(/\)/g, '%29')
            .replace(/\(/g, '%28');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I've answered my own question after a sleepless night .. here's how to correctly encode in JavaScript (also for node.js)

```
p = encodeURIComponent(p)
            .replace(/%2F/g, '/')
            .replace(/\)/g, '%29')
            .replace(/\(/g, '%28')
            .replace(/!/g,'%21');
    if (p[0] === '/') { p = p.slice(1); }
```

Also we were adding the path to the body of the request as well as the url .. big mistake.  Make sure that the body of the request ONLY contains expected parameters.